# Validation - Returning the first error for an AJAX response

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm probably over complicating things where it's not needed, but I have a form that is submitted via AJAX and then validated. I'm trying to return the first error that occurs, but I can only ever seem to fetch **validation.required** which of course is useless to me; I can't tell the user which field failed and nor can I translate an appropriate error message.

What gives? How can I fetch a human-friendly error message and return it back as a JSON response?

Here's what I've got going so far... The biggest how-do-I is fetching the attribute name for the error message, but maybe there's a far easier way to manage this altogether...

```
/**
 * Adds a new post to the system
 *
 * @param   Request $request
 * @return  json
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // run validation
    if(!empty($validator = $this->validate($request)))
    {
        return response()->json(trans('global/'.$validator->first(), ['attribute' => 'how to get attribute?!?!']), 400);
    }

    // some other logic...
}


/**
 * Validates a post add or post update request
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   Request $request
 * @return  mixed
 */
private function validate(Request $request)
{
    // set-up validation rules
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'username'      => 'max:255|required',
        'email'         => 'email',
        'service'       => 'numeric|required',
    ]);

    $validator->setAttributeNames([
        'username'      => "Username",
        'service'       => "Service",
    ]);

    // run validation
    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return $validator->errors();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use code above in your controller `store` method and do not override `validate` method:

```
    $rules      = [
        'username' => 'max:255|required',
        'email'    => 'email',
        'service'  => 'numeric|required',
    ];
    $attributes = [
        'username' => "Username",
        'service'  => "Service",
    ];
    $this->validate($request, $rules, [], $attributes);
```

It will automatically returns errors json if validation fails.
Errors example:

```
{"username":["The Username field is required."],"service":["The Service field is required."]}
```